# Retrieving data through mysql using function and use in the select box?

Tags: php, html, mysql, function

i write a program to retrieve the data through MySQL using function now i have a problem that how i use it in the select box?

Code for this is given below,

```
function selectdata(){
$select="SELECT * FROM table_name";

$run=mysql_query($select);

while($fetch=mysql_fetch_array($run)){
 $field_name.=$fetch['field_name'];


}
return $field_name;
}
```

HTML:

```
<select name="office_name">

<option value=""><?php echo selectdata(); ?></option>

</select>
```

it is showing all the data in one field

any help??

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? Did you want a new `<option>` element for each row from the table?

Comment: Don't use `mysql_` extensions it's deprecated, use `PDO` or `msqli_` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do like this

```
function selectdata(){
   $select="SELECT * FROM table_name";

   $run=mysql_query($select);
   $field_name = '';
   while($fetch=mysql_fetch_array($run)){
       $field_name.="<option value=''>" . $fetch['field_name'] . "</option>";
   }
   return $field_name;
}
```

And in html

```
<select name="office_name">
<?php echo selectdata(); ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're echoing your string into one option value. A better way would be to return an `array` from `selectdata()` and then loop through it in your html like:

```
function selectdata(){
    $select="SELECT * FROM table_name";

    $run=mysql_query($select);
    $fields = array()
    while($fetch=mysql_fetch_array($run)){
        $fields[] = $fetch['field_name'];
    }
    return $fields;
}
```

And then

```
<select name="office_name">
    <?php foreach(selectdata() as $option): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $option; ?>"><?php echo $option; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

This way, you're keeping HTML out of your PHP.

Comment: Why would you want to do a loop twice? If you are already going trough all the rows, why not use it.

Comment: It allows you to reuse the `selectdata` function elsewhere as it wouldn't contain the HTML. Example: Once the user submits their form data you want to validate that it's one of the allowed options. You could then do `in_array($_POST['office_name'], selectdata())`. It's all about reusability and keeping HTML away from your PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one..Not sure the syntax is correct.

```
function selectdata(){
$select="SELECT * FROM table_name";

$run=mysql_query($select);

while($fetch=mysql_fetch_array($run)){
 $field_name.= "<option value=>" .$fetch['field_name']."</option>";
}
return $field_name;
}
```

HTML:

```
<select name="office_name">
<?php echo selectdata(); ?>
</select>
```

Comment: you are missing the parenthesis for the `value`-Attribute as well as its content.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("YOUR QUERY HERE"); // Run your query

echo '<select name="DROP DOWN NAME">'; // Open your drop down box

// Loop through the query results, outputing the options one by one
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
   echo '<option value="'.$row['something'].'">'.$row['something'].'</option>';
}

echo '</select>';// Close your drop down box





?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use as following sample,

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM terms";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
   $term[$row{'term_id'}] = $row{'term_name'};
}
?>
    <select id="mass_term"  name="mass_term" style="width:125px;" >
   <?php foreach($term as $key=>$value){ ?>
      <option <?php echo ($key==$termid)?'selected="selected"':'' ?> value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $value; ?></option>
   <?php } ?>
    </select>
```