# echo is showing output in page source instead of on page

Tags: php

I made a table in php and wanted to show the Id's in the dropdown select menu by making a separate file for php. So the code in main file is:

```
<?php include "functions.php";?>
<form action="login_update.php" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control">
            </div>

           <div class="form-group">
               <select name="id" id="">
                   <?php  

                        showAllData();
                   echo "<br>"."askfkldfjl;adfafladfdf";
                    ?>
               </select>
           </div>

            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="update">
       </form>
```

The code of functions.php is :

```
<?php 

function showAllData(){


    $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','****','loginapp');
    if($connection){
        echo "We are connected. a=".$a."<br>";
    }else{
        die("Database connection failed");
    }
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    if($result){
        echo("<br>"." <b><h6>We are successful</h6></b>");
    }
    else {        
        die("Query FAILED" . mysqli_error());
    }
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  {
      $id = $row["id"];

      echo"<option value='$id'>$id</option>";


    }


}
?>
```

The expected output was :
[image]

**But the output is:**
[image]

So the top two lines in the above screenshot are not printing.

These lines are shown in the INSPECT ELEMENT in chrome.

[image]

I forgot to mention the echo command:

```
echo "<br>"."askfkldfjl;adfafladfdf";
```

below show all data is also not working.

Comment: Echoing plain text inside `select` is not a good idea. Open generated source code and see what is there.

Comment: try die() after echo

Comment: Do you have display errors enabled? If you do not know, then write and obvious PHP error. and execute. it should give you an error message. If it does not then you HAVE an error that is not being showed. Also if you have enable PHP logs please output what the web server is saying.

Comment: you could do echo "<option>We are connected. a=".$a."</option>" - that way it will show in the select ...

Comment: But the echo below showAllData() is also not working.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937460/retrieving-data-through-mysql-using-function-and-use-in-the-select-box) out , you `did't return` any data from function that's why it is not printing anything.

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake.
Actually you wrote a code in selectbox and you dont add option so thats why it is not show in html
So write a code like below code so its show in select box as option.

```
<div class="form-group">
               <select name="id" id="">
                  <option> <?php  

                        showAllData();
                   echo "<br>"."askfkldfjl;adfafladfdf";
                    ?></option>
               </select>
           </div>
```

And If you want to show option from `showAllData();` function, the you have return the html.

For this update your `showAllData();` function with below code:

```
function showAllData(){
     $options="";

    $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','****','loginapp');
    if($connection){
        echo "We are connected. a=".$a."<br>";
    }else{
        die("Database connection failed");
    }
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    if($result){
        echo("<br>"." <b><h6>We are successful</h6></b>");
    }
    else {        
        die("Query FAILED" . mysqli_error());
    }
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  {
      $id = $row["id"];

      $options.="<option value='$id'>$id</option>";


    }
    return $options;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the `PHP` function `showAllData()` before the `HTML` `<select>` element.
Because the `<select>` element awaits for an `<option>` element, but all another text will not be visible on page.

E.g.:

```
   <div class="form-group">
       <?php showAllData(); ?>
   </div>

<?php 

function showAllData(){


    $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','****','loginapp');
    if($connection){
        echo "We are connected. a=".$a."<br>";
    }else{
        die("Database connection failed");
    }
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    if($result){
        echo("<br>"." <b><h6>We are successful</h6></b>");
    }
    else {        
        die("Query FAILED" . mysqli_error());
    }

    echo '<select name="id" id="">';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  {
      $id = $row["id"];

      echo"<option value='$id'>$id</option>";


    }
    echo "</select>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why you are putting `<br>` inside the select tag? select tag only accept the options tag under it, so please remove br tag and all extra strings inside the select tag. and you should echo the message above the select tag if you want to show your users.
>
> Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code is mixed up.
You can use below code. Create an array which gives you values which you needs to show in select.

```
<?php 

function showAllData(){
    $idArr = array('msg'=>'','data'=>'','status'=>0);    
    $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','****','loginapp');
    if($connection){
        $idArr['msg'] = "We are connected";
        $idArr['status'] = 1;
    }else{
        $idArr['msg'] = "Database connection failed"; 
        $idArr['status'] = 0;
    }
    if($idArr['status'] == 1){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
        if($result){
            $idArr['msg'] = "We are successful";
            $idArr['status'] = 1;               
        }else {        
            $idArr['msg'] = "Query FAILED" . mysqli_error(); 
            $idArr['status'] = 0;  
        }
        if($idArr['status'] == 1){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  {
                 $idArr['data'][] = $row["section_id"];
            }
        }        
    }   
    return $idArr;
}
$idArr = showAllData();
?>

<?php 
if(!empty($idArr['data'])){
    echo "We are connected<br>";
    echo("<br>"." <b><h6>We are successful</h6></b>");
    ?>
    <form action="login_update.php" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control">
            </div>

           <div class="form-group">
               <select name="id" id="">
                   <option value="0">--Select--</option>
                   <?php 
                       foreach ($idArr['data'] as $key => $value) {
                           echo"<option value='$value'>$value</option>";
                       }
                   ?>
               </select>
           </div>

            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="update">
       </form>

<?php }else{
    echo $idArr['msg'];
}

?>
```